# How to add cordova as a pod dependency

Tags: ios, cordova, mobile, cocoapods, hybrid

I'd like to add cordova as a pod dependency, just like I do for other dependencies.

```
use_frameworks!

target 'MyApp' do
  pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.3'
  pod 'Cordova' 
end
```

When I run pod install, I receive: "Unable to find a specification for `Cordova`"